# Code to replace one instance of a letter with 2 more recursive

Tags: java, string, recursion, input, methods

I'm trying to replace every instance of a with 3 b's, I have the code to replace it with one b but I can't figure how to put in multiple instances of the letter. I would use a string instead of a char as it cant hold more the one character but that gives me an error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class replace 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String words = input.nextLine();
    char from = 'a';
    char to = 'b';

    System.out.println(replace(words, from, to));
  }

  public static String replace(String s, char from, char to){
    if (s.length() < 1) 
    {
      return s;
    }
    else 
    {
      char first = from == s.charAt(0) ? to : s.charAt(0);
      return first + replace(s.substring(1), from, to);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `words = words.replace("a", "bbb");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class replace 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String words = input.nextLine();
    String from = "a";
    String to = "bbb";

    System.out.println(replace(words, from, to));
  }

  public static String replace(String s, String from, String to){
    if (s.length() < 1) 
    {
      return s;
    }
    else 
    {
      String first = from.equals(s.substring(0,1)) ? to : s.substring(0,1);
      return first + replace(s.substring(1), from, to);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt you not be able to use the ? operator when dealing with strings though?